# Как задать название контейнера

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Как в docker-compose переименовать название контейнера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) нужно использовать директиву `container_name`

```
services:
  docker:
    image: docker:latest
    container_name: custom-conainer-name
```

Но учтите, что этот параметр игнорируется при работе докера в Swarm режиме.

Comment: Да, нашёл. Спасибо.